# Script is running but isn't connecting to google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

i am having a problem connecting my script to my google sheets

the script i am trying to run is as below. i have used it previously however i recently got a new gmail account and i am unsure if this might be problem. if so i don't know how to fix this.

any help would be amazing the link to the Sheet is below
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/100aGV6VXBDmcNAUOQDDiODfK0l5xk2ZnrmmtlnOehHc/edit#gid=1052062767

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdyxL.png)

Many thanks :):)

Comment: All scripts in a project have access to all sheets in the container that contains the project

Comment: Please post the code into the question.

Comment: Do you have a sheet named 1?

Comment: The code in the image does not do anything.

Comment: [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: The link to your spreadsheet is not public